# Cross join a table with itself Impala SQL Cloudera

Tags: sql, impala

I have a table with patient id and conditions 
about 400 conditions

I want to see where there is overlap between two conditions for every conditions
so 400 choose 2 order doesn't matter.

essentially this is source table

[image]

this would be the result
impala does not support self join so .... looking

[image]

Comment: I haven't used Impala, so I'd be shocked if it didn't support self joins.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following should work:

```
select s1.condition, s2.condition, count(*) as num_patients
from source s1 join
     source s2
     on s1.patientid = s2.patientid
group by s1.condition, s2.condition;
```

This does not fully answer your question -- because it leaves out the `0` values.  I want to be sure this works before addressing the rest of the problem.